# How to debug a crashing release build?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, release

My debug builds don't crash, but the release builds do.

I've modified the Run scheme to use produce TestFlight release build and install it on my device. This works. But the app keeps crashing during usage. The Organizer window gives me no device logs. There are no crash reports. Nothing at all.

How do the Pros do it?

Comment: And TestFlight doesn't give you an exception report?

Comment: Change the scheme in your Xcode project so that the "Run" settings uses the release build, then push play as normal.  If you are having trouble getting the debugger to work, make sure you sign with your development certificate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some possibilities:

- Get a console app for your iPhone and look at the console on your device (e.g. https://itunes.apple.com/nl/app/console/id317676250?mt=8)
- Use another web service like BugSense (www.bugsense.com) to receive online crash reports
- Your Organizer window should give you device logs anyway (if the device is connected, that is). You can also try to get the device logs with another Apple tool (http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1465)

Answer (score 1):

Integrate the TestFlight SDK in your app: https://testflightapp.com/sdk/